# Change the color of several parts of a line plot according to a loop

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I want to change the color of some parts of a line plot.
Here my original time series :

```
{'ICP': {0: 5.070969052803593,
  1: 5.4817961734227065,
  2: 6.397815732226121,
  3: 6.0582909835985195,
  4: 6.305368037683179,
  5: 5.913004902475054,
  6: 6.108737887168982,
  7: 5.80118107371289,
  8: 6.7867417878010965,
  9: 5.088879690164107},
 'Timestamp': {0: Timestamp('2020-12-16 10:04:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2020-12-16 10:05:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2020-12-16 10:06:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2020-12-16 10:07:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2020-12-16 10:08:00'),
  5: Timestamp('2020-12-16 10:09:00'),
  6: Timestamp('2020-12-16 10:10:00'),
  7: Timestamp('2020-12-16 10:11:00'),
  8: Timestamp('2020-12-16 10:12:00'),
  9: Timestamp('2020-12-16 10:13:00')}}
```

For instance, I plot my dataframe :

[image]

I have an dataframe like that :

```
{'BeginDate': {0: Timestamp('2020-12-16 10:04:00'),
  14: Timestamp('2020-12-17 03:53:00'),
  16: Timestamp('2020-12-17 18:09:00'),
  18: Timestamp('2020-12-18 03:39:00'),
  20: Timestamp('2020-12-19 00:11:00'),
  24: Timestamp('2020-12-19 04:27:00'),
  25: Timestamp('2020-12-19 08:55:00'),
  28: Timestamp('2020-12-19 09:15:00'),
  32: Timestamp('2020-12-19 13:50:00'),
  33: Timestamp('2020-12-19 14:53:00')},
 'EndDate': {0: Timestamp('2020-12-17 03:12:00'),
  14: Timestamp('2020-12-17 18:04:00'),
  16: Timestamp('2020-12-18 03:36:00'),
  18: Timestamp('2020-12-19 00:08:00'),
  20: Timestamp('2020-12-19 04:17:00'),
  24: Timestamp('2020-12-19 08:54:00'),
  25: Timestamp('2020-12-19 09:12:00'),
  28: Timestamp('2020-12-19 13:44:00'),
  32: Timestamp('2020-12-19 14:52:00'),
  33: Timestamp('2020-12-19 18:14:00')}}
```

For each row of the dataframe, I want to change the color of the line plot between the two dates.
What I want to have :

[image]

I can plot only 'one' part, by using this code :

```
       # The entire time series    
        ax = df['ICP'].plot(figsize = (16,5), title = "ICP")
        ax.set(xlabel='Dates', ylabel='ICP')
       # The orange part (a row of the dataframe, between two dates)
        ax = test['ICP'].plot(figsize = (16,5), title = "ICP")
        ax.set(xlabel='Dates', ylabel='ICP')
```

Can I change the color of the different range by using a loop ? Or maybe an other method ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: You can use the c parameter to set the color. `.plot(c="red")`. Could you please post the top n rows of your dataframe using `df.head(n).to_dict()` to make it easier for us to reproduce and give you a working example.

Comment: Sure, I added dictionary to my post ! Thanks!

Comment: are you breaking this up into different lines or are you wanting to change colour on just the one line at certain points ?

Comment: Just to change colour on just the one line at certain points ! I tried som things with a loop (iterate over my dataframe to get begin date and end date), but it don't work ...